# stop journald showing the message but forward to syslog

Tags: systemd, syslog, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I want to forward the logs from my systemd service to syslog, but do not want to show them when doing the `systemctl status <service>`. If i use the parameter, `StandardOutput=null` in systemd service file, it do not show in status but also do not forward it to the syslog. I want to forward them to syslog without storing/showing in journald/systemctl status. How to achieve this?